# Angular unit testing router events

Tags: angular, unit-testing, routes, mocking, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to mock router.events.subscribe() but it's not working. I tried to provide and event but I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'root'). How can I do it?
TS code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            this.splitRoutes();
        });
    }

    private splitRoutes() {
        const routes = this.router.url.toString().split('/');
            }
        }
    }
```

spec.ts:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [{
        provide: Router,
        useValue: {
          url: '/non-pdp/phases/8',
          events: of(
            new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/#/non-pdp/phases/8', 'http://localhost:4200/#/non-pdp/phases/8')),
          navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
        }],
      })
    .compileComponents();
});
```

Comment: Are you also importing `RouterTestingModule`? if yes, you may have to remove it and try

Comment: In spec.ts I don't

Comment: Could you please add the whole text of error. It's not clear in which object it tries to access `root` property

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'root')

    at Object.rootRoute [as useFactory] . I can't post more but this is it